# How to show lyrics on my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, mp3

Now I'm going to create audio player app on my Iphone
So, I was looking for some information about building music app with Swift.
There were many information but, I could not find one thing it is how can I show song lyrics on my phone.
Although already there are many music app that supported to show lyrics but I need customized app only for me. So I have to build music app only for me.
I just want to play and pause song and show playlist and show lyrics.
Maybe are there reference? If there are reference. Please inform me.

Comment: Please inform free APIs.

Comment: @Josh Caswell I have some general architecture questions I'd like to bounce off of some dev groups, but I know that's not really stackoverflow's mission. There are other forums under the stackoverflow family though--do you know of any that are geared to that sort of thing?

Comment: Lyrics are just text. Are you asking how to show text using Swift? Or are you asking how to find the lyrics for each mp3? For finding... Some mp3's have the lyrics embedded in the ID3 metadata bytes and for some lyrics you'll have to use internet (load page as text and extract the lyrics from html text).

Answer (score 1):

@D Why, It's hard to tell what aspect of development you might be asking about specifically. I've been there before myself--wanting to hash out some high level ideas-- so I'd like to help out.

I'd say start with finding a song lyrics database; something like [mldb.org](http://www.mldb.org). The [programmableweb.com](https://www.programmableweb.com/) contains APIs that may already exist for what you have in mind. Next, check out the dev communities (ObjC, RubyMotion, etc.) for audiobooks, etc. Here's an [example out of Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/iphone/abplayer_iphone.aspx) that's pretty old already, but it will give you an idea.